# Private NSManagedObjectContexts and deleting objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Core Data stack with a main managed object context with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.

The user can initiate a task on a managed object that can take a long time, so it is performed on a separate context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[context setParentContext:mainMOC];
Person *samePerson = (Person *)[context objectWithID:person.objectID];
[context performBlock:^{
    // BLOCK 1
    // do lots of work

    // then update the managed object
    samePerson.value = someCalculatedValue;

    // save the private context
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    [mainMOC performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if (![mainMOC save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}];
```

This works fine, and the main MOC gets updated properly, NSFetchedResultsController hooked up to it perform properly, etc.

The problem is with deleting. I have this setup to delete objects:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[context setParentContext:mainMOC];
[context performBlock:^{
    // BLOCK 2
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *all = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!all) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching: %@", error);
    } else {
        for (NSManagedObject *person in all) {
            [context deleteObject:person];
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", error);
        }

        [mainMOC performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            if (![mainMOC save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Now if I do this **delete operation** (Block 2) during the time it takes to perform the **long-duration task** (Block 1), then the delete operation finishes quickly, and saves to main context. After a while Block 1 finishes, and when it saves the mainMOC at its end, we get a seemingly obvious crash:

```
CoreData could not fulfill a fault for ...
```

My question is: how do I perform a task such as Block 1 with the possibility of its object being deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are both background tasks that cannot run at the same time, try using semaphores to protect access to them.

eg. for an instance variable:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t _backgroundProcessingSemaphore;
```

Lazily initialised using something like:

```
- (dispatch_semaphore_t)backgroundProcessingSemaphore
{
    if (!_backgroundProcessingSemaphore) {
        _backgroundProcessingSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    }
    return _backgroundProcessingSemaphore;
}
```

Surround the critical code with:

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.backgroundProcessingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
// Critical code
dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.backgroundProcessingSemaphore);
```

Only one critical section of code can then run at any point in time. The block that calls dispatch_semaphore_wait will block if the semaphore is already taken, until it is freed up.

You also probably want to think about splitting your long-duration task up so that it will run in discrete batches if you're not already doing so - this is useful if the long running background task timer is about to expire while you still have work to do - you can stop and restart from the appropriate point on next launch.

Other options would involve forcing a save on block 1 before block 2 saves itself, but this starts to get messy. Much easier to ensure the two competing blocks cannot overlap.

Comment: I guess I was wondering if there was a best pattern for dealing with deleted managed objects in a multi-threaded environment. I was hoping for something else than synchronizing or using a serial queue. Otherwise all my managed object code would require such semaphores won't they?

Comment: Look into setting the mergePolicy on your context, and try responding to the save as using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: to try to merge the changes from your delete in to the work being done on the long running context before saving. You've got two different contexts stepping on each others toes - there's going to be some work involved in getting them to coexist - either merge the changes, or keep them apart.